# XML DOM to get text within a tag

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, vbscript

I have an XPath query `//*[local-name()='Home Query Data']`, tested [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath). 
Now I have to execute this XPath to return all the text from within `<Home Query Data> --- </Home Query Data>` tag.

What DOM selector should I use to select entire text from within the tag?
Like: `objMSXML.selectNodes(XPath)`

**Edit**

I am using VBScript for my programming. My code is below:

```vb
Sub ReadXml(FileName)
  Dim nodeinfo (4)
  Dim sXPath
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set fileObj = fso.GetFile(FileName)
  objMSXML.async = True
  objMSXML.load FileName

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
  sXPath = "//*[local-name()='Home Query Data']"
  End If
  Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
  If querySubject Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sXPath, "failed" ** Error type mismatch [string "failed"]**
  Else
    For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
      MsgBox node
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

I have copied it for some other post and unable to figure out how to return entire text within XML tag.

I have a problem in this portion:

```vb
Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
If querySubject Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox sXPath, "failed"
Else
  For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
    MsgBox node
  Next
End If
```

**Edit2**

My Working XML is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
   <name locale="en">Stage Query Data</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>Our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<drink>
   <name locale="en">Home Query Data</name>
  <price>$4.50</price>
  <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
  <calories>600</calories>
</drink>
<mix>
   <name locale="en">Report Query Data</name>
  <price>$6.95</price>
  <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
  <calories>950</calories>
</mix>
</breakfast_menu>
```

I need to capture text within tag `<drink>` whose name is `Home Query Data`.

```
<name locale="en">Home Query Data</name>
      <price>$4.50</price>
      <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
      <calories>600</calories>
```

Currently I am getting at MsgBox sXPath, "failed" ** Error type mismatch [string "failed"]**

Comment: have you tried `node.text`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763798.aspx

Comment: the problem with xpath. it says type mismatch sxpath....

Comment: Show the complete error message. Also show a representative (working) sample of your XML data.

Comment: Plese have a look at the update above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `text()` attribute selector, not the `local-name()` function. The latter gets the name of a node, not its content.

Also, your `MsgBox` call is invalid - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx.

The following works as expected:

```vb
Sub ReadXML(FileName)
  Dim sXPath
  Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
  objMSXML.load FileName

  If objMSXML.parseError = 0 Then
    sXPath = "//*[name/text()='Home Query Data']"
    Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
    If querySubject Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox sXPath, 0, "failed"
    Else
      For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
        MsgBox node.text
      Next
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox objMSXML.parseError
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 'objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)' is wrong, It doesn't return node.

Comment: some other method than `selectSingleNode(sXPath)` is required